# Memory of first element in dynamic char array

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My array is defined like this

```
int buffSize = 80;
char* buff = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * buffSize);
```

First, I thought `&buff` should be the same as `&buff[0]`, but apparently, it isn't! Did I miss something here?
This statement prints two different values for those two:

```
    printf("COMPARE: buff=%u, buff[0]=%u\n", &buff, &buff[0]);
```

Second, the reason I asked is because I'm trying to create a big buffer and "manually" divide it up to use with `getline`. 
Basically, I'd like to do something like this:

```
int byte_read, total_read = 0;
do
{
   read = getline(&buff[totalRead], buffSize, inFile); //where inFile is just a file handler
  totalRead += read;
}
while (byte_read > 0);
```

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You probably wanted `buffsize - total_read` in the `getline` call, otherwise you can overflow.

Comment: You seem to be mentally confusing a pointer with the thing it is pointing to. Don't do this; they are two completely separate entities.

Comment: "I'm trying to create a big buffer and manually divide it up to use with getline." - that doesn't make any sense. How is that different to just reading the whole file into a buffer?

Answer (score 4):

`buff` is a pointer, and `&buff` is the address of that pointer. On the other hand, `&buff[0]` is the address of the location the pointer points to, and should have the same value as `buff`.

In summary, expect `buff` and `&buff[0]` to have the same value.

Comment: So because `getline` takes `&buff`, which is the address of the pointer to the char array, presumably, there's no clean way to do what I want as described above?

Comment: @abcXYZ `getline` isn't taking `&buff`. I think you didn't understand my answer.

Comment: This page said `getline` takes the address of the pointer, i.e., `&buff`:
http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html
I must've misunderstood something?

Comment: @abcXYZ yes, it takes `&buff`, not `&buff[totalRead]`. This is because it may make the pointer point elsewhere (to a new memory allocation). It has no "append" functionality.

Comment: @M.M Right. It does take `&buff`, but is there anyway I can  specify where it starts writing the value to in the buffer I pass?

Comment: @abcXYZ No there is not.

Comment: @abcXYZ I see, you mean the `getline` function expects a pointer to a pointer, not that you pass `&buff` in your own code. Yes, that is correct. It expects a pointer to a pointer, so it can set the location that pointer points to. Sorry for the misunderstanding.